# How can I write and read bool values into/from cookies?

Tags: html, asp.net, cookies, razor, forms

I want to save the state of checkboxes in an html form on submit to cookies, and then enable/disable other parts of my site based on those cookie values.

I've started out with code like this:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>(Not really) Opt In or Out</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectTwitter" name="selectTwitter" >I'm Twitterpated!</input><br />
```

. . .

Razor:

@{
    var twitterSelected = false;
    . . .

```
if (IsPost)
{
    twitterSelected = Request["selectTwitter"].AsBool();
    Response.Cookies["TwitterSelected"].Value = twitterSelected.ToString(); // Doesn't seem to accept saving boolean vals - saved as "false" or "true"?
    Response.Cookies["TwitterSelected"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
. . .
```

...but am stuck on how to check or uncheck the checkboxes based on possibly existing cookie vals:

```
if (Request.Cookies["selectTwitter"] != null)
{
    // what now?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are strings. You'll need to convert the cookie value to the type you want. The boolean values are being saved as `true` or `false` because that's the string representation of a boolean.

```
var selectTwitterCookie = Request.Cookies["selectTwitter"];
bool selectTwitter = false;

if(selectTwitterCookie != null)
{
    bool.TryParse(selectTwitterCookie, out selectTwitter);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `Convert.ToBoolean(selectTwitterCookie)`.