# Can I toggle the visibility of a tab based on its title?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, razor

This is a similar question to the one here: [Why are my cookie settings not being applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775435/why-are-my-cookie-settings-not-being-applied)

I know this is kludgy, but I haven't found another way to accomplish this - I want to read a cookie, and based on the cookie val (either "true" or "false") toggle a tab's visibility on or off, using a combination of Razor/C#, HTML, and jQuery.

What I've come up with is to base the div's "title" property on that, with Razor code, and then, in jQuery, read that property val to set the visibility val, something like this:

Razor:

```
string selectTwitterCookie = Request.Cookies["selectTwitter"].Value;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter" title=@selectTwitterCookie>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").title == "true") {
    $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").visible("visible");
} else {
    $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").visible("not visible");
}
```

...of course, "not visible" is not what I really need. I would rather code it more directly, such as something like this:

```
($("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").title == "true") ?  $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").visible("visible") : $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").visible("invisible");
```

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

### UPDATE

Okay, another odd situation. Looking at values in CDT, I see that all of the tabs have the same class ("ui-tabs-anchor"):

```
<a href="#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Twitterpated</a>
<a href="#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Bing" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Bingo</a>
```

...so they don't seem to have their html affected by the class="display-@WhateverCookie" that I added in code:

```
<div id="duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter" class="display-@TwitterCookie">
```

...yet, those with that class added won't display anything in their iframe - except Twitter; Twitter works fine... so, it's back to the coding board*, although sometimes it feels more like a Ouija board or a draft board.

- Sung to the melody of "Back to the Barrooms" by Merle Haggard.

### UPDATE 2

Changing it to this allows the iframe to work again:

```
class="display-"+@BingCookie
```

(instead of class="display-@BingCookie")

But it's interesting - CDT still doesn't seem to be aware of the on-the-fly created class.

### UPDATE 3

Bizarre...even after adding a title to the html:

```
<div id="duckbilledPlatypusTab-BingSearch" style="min-height: 50vh" title="Bla" class="display-"+@BingCookie>
```

...and this to the end of the jQuery ready method:

```
if ($("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Bing").attr('title') == "true") {
    $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Bing").css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Bing").css('display', 'none');
}
```

...the tab remains visible.

CDT sees the element as:

```
<div id="dynaMashTab-Bingo" style="min-height: 50vh;" title="bla" class="display- ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" +@bingocookie="" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false"></div>
```

IOW, the "class" declaration looks completely wacky...

Comment: Use the `.css()` method: `$("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").css('display', 'none')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.css()` method in jQuery and set `display` for the element, and you must get an attribute with `.attr()` method:

```
if ($("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").attr('title') == "true") {
    $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").css('display', 'none');
}
```

References:

- [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) - jQuery API Documentation

---

### TIP

However, there is no need to use jQuery here actually, you can do it with your template engine (Razor).
Something like this:

```
<div id="duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter" class="display-@selectTwitterCookie">
```

And in your CSS you will have:

```
.display-true { display: block; }
.display-false { display: none; }
```

Comment: This actually is not quite working yet; in fact, adding that code caused the tab to not be invisible, but its *contents* to be invisible, at all times. IOW, the iframe inside it goes blank.

Comment: @ClayShannon I don't know much about razor template engine, but I think something like this must be translat correctly by razor: `class="display-@BingCookie"` (you can check it in the output HTML). But this you wrote: `class="display-"+@BingCookie` is completely wrong as you put `@BingCookie` outside the quotation marks of `class` attribute, and, also I think `+` operator wouldn't work correctly there.

Comment: I changed it to class="display-"+@BingCookie from class = "display-@BingCookie" because the latter was not working, in fact causing none of the tabs so decorated to display content in their iframes at all. It's the tabs themselves I'm trying to conditionally hide, not their content within their iframes.

Answer (score 1):

- Solution 1:

  ```
  if ($("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").attr('title') === "true") {
      $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").show();
  } else {
      $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").hide();
  }
  ```
- Solution 2:

  ```
  if ($("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").attr('title') === "true") {
      // Can use hidden OR display-none based on your requirement
      $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
      // Can use hidden OR display-none based on your requirement
      $("#duckbilledPlatypusTab-Twitter").addClass("hidden");
  }
  ```

  CSS:

  ```
  .hidden {visibility: hidden !important;} 
  .display-none {display: none !important;}
  ```

NOTE: *Hopefully you do this as part of $(document).ready() OR someother place where the value of selectTwitterCookie is available and the DOM is ready.*